# how to curl datetimefield to django

Tags: python, django, curl, django-models

How can I make a cURL-type request to my django app where the `POST` data includes a `DateTimeField`?  models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime    

class usageHistory(models.Model):

    fk_employee_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    fk_version = models.BigIntegerField()
    fk_instrument = models.BigIntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *

class usageHistoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = usageHistory
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(usageHistory, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
```

I don't know what it wants in the field.  perhaps `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`?  I really have no idea.  I can find lots of helps online for serializing the `DateTimeField`, but not on how to feed info *into* it.  I know the `POST` data is a `string`, so what's django expecting to receive?

Comment: Your classes really should start with an uppercase letter to follow Python class naming convention. `UsageHistory` and `UsageHistoryForm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) shows exactly what formats it accepts and how to customize that.

> If no input_formats argument is provided, the default input formats are:
>
> ```
> ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',    # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
>  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',       # '2006-10-25 14:30'
>  '%Y-%m-%d',             # '2006-10-25'
>  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',    # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
>  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',       # '10/25/2006 14:30'
>  '%m/%d/%Y',             # '10/25/2006'
>  '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',    # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
>  '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',       # '10/25/06 14:30'
>  '%m/%d/%y']             # '10/25/06'
> ```

Comment: thank you most of all for providing the link.  I was reading through the models docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField), but it didn't really say, I didn't consider that the forms docs would say more.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Django's ModelForm should automatically represent your datetime in the format it expects. Additionally, it will validate that input if a user tries to mangle the date value.

Try submitting your form and looking in the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>). This will show you the POST request your form makes and the string format that Django accepts.

Bear in mind that the widget Django uses is actually [two separate text fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField); One for date, the other for time. So you'll need to make sure you submit both in your POST request.